# How to do code splitting for Node.js modules with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, code-splitting

All articles I can find are about splitting code for web applications.

What if I have a two entry points in a Node.js module (NPM package), and each of those two entry points import some common code?

I have two entry points. I want to publish those on NPM in a package. They import some of the same files, so I don't want both bundles to contain duplicate code.

When bundling those two entry points, how would we generate a third module with the common code, and have those two entry points import it?

The output of the two entry points would be CommonJS format (for Node.js), and somehow Webpack would have the two entry points import the stuff from the third file (with `require()`).

Can this be done with Webpack?

(Please don't ask why I'm using Webpack with Node modules. )

Answer (score 0):

Webpack only support ES dynamic import when code splitting, which means you can only use `import()`.

Node.js `require()` is unsupported.